# Axios interceptor not working anymore in last version (1.1.3)

Tags: axios, access-token, bearer-token

I recently upgraded axios in one of my project (from 0.27 to 1.1.3) and the interceptor I created to refresh the user's access token doesn't work anymore, u can find in the screenshot bellow the error I'm having. I searched online but can't find anything working.
To precise, whenever the user's access token expires, my back end send the 401 error and so the interceptor is called. The returned token is good as well as the setting to the headers.
Thank you in advance for your time.

```js
import axios from "axios";
import router from "@/router";
import store from "@/store/index";

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:3000",
});

instance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    return response;
  },
  async (error) => {
    const originalRequest = error.config;
    console.log("error:", error);
    if (
      error.config.url != "users/refreshToken" &&
      error.response.status === 401 &&
      !originalRequest._retry
    ) {
      originalRequest._retry = true;
      await instance
        .get("users/refreshToken", { withCredentials: true })
        .then((response) => {
          const token = response.data.accessToken;
          console.log("token:", token);
          store.state.token = token;
          instance.defaults.headers.common["authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
          originalRequest.headers["authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
          localStorage.setItem("token", token);
        })
        .catch(() => {
          store.commit("logout");
          localStorage.removeItem("token");
          router.push({ name: "login", params: { error: "refreshToken" } });
        });
      return instance(originalRequest);
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

export default instance;
```

The error :

[image]

Comment: This is probably fixed in the latest version of Axios (v1.2.2 as of writing). In my opnion, Axios has been extremely unstable since v1.0.0 and I cannot recommend it. If you need something reliable that also supports interceptors, check out [ky](https://github.com/sindresorhus/ky)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about [a bug in Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5283) that has since been fixed